# How can i use bing traffic api on openlayers 2?

Tags: openlayers, bing-maps

I have this code to add hybrid bing map to my openlayers application. How can I add traffic flow layer on it?

what should be the type?

```js
layerBingHybrid = new OpenLayers.Layer.Bing({
    key: "BING_MAPS_Key",
    type: "AerialWithLabels",
    name: "Bing Hybrid"
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The traffic flow data in Bing Maps can only be used inside of Bing Maps controls and not in 3rd party or open source controls.